# Top Y axis value is not visible

Tags: matplotlib, graph

I am not able to correctly annotate Y axis sticks values. Top of annotation is always missing
I have tried use plt.ylim values but it does not work. What you suggest to try more ?
[image]

```
y_lim_min = int(Point_umb['Subsidence_3'])-(int(Point_umb['Subsidence_3']) %5)
y_lim_max = int(y[0])+(5-(int(y[0]) %5))
plt.ylim(bottom=y_lim_min, top=y_lim_max)


if (y_lim_max-y_lim_min)<5.01:
    plt.yticks(np.arange(y_lim_min,y_lim_max,1))
    print('Üks')
    print(y_lim_max)
elif ((y_lim_max-y_lim_min)>5.01) and ((y_lim_max-y_lim_min)<20.01):
    plt.yticks(np.arange(y_lim_min,y_lim_max,5))
    print('viis')
    print(y_lim_max)
else:
    plt.yticks(np.arange(y_lim_min,y_lim_max,10))
    print('muu')
    print(y_lim_max-y_lim_min)
    print(y_lim_max)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(['InSAR 18.02.2023','Validation trend','Threshold 1','Threshold 2','Threshold 3'],loc='upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2),
          ncol=5)

plt.title('Subsidence rate of '+ name, fontsize=30)

plt.savefig("./images/"+ name+'.png',bbox_inches = "tight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please create some code with dummy data to show exactly what you want to do? Which value do you want to see at the question mark?  Which ylim do you want to set.  In this case `ax.set_ylim(ymax=-0.499999)` could be worth a try.  Are you using the automatic yticks? Or are you placing them explicitly?  (Without code there is an awful lot of guess work.)

Comment: it should be -5. I used 
plt.ylim(bottom=-45, top=-5)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-45,-5,10))
Additonally  I tried slightly smaler and bigger values to add ymin and ymax
plt.ylim(bottom=-46, top=-4)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-46,-4,10))
It did not worked

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75897985/edit) a full working reproducible example code. How did you create the plots? Are you working with subplots? ....?  If you have subplots, the axes interface is recommended instead of the old plt interface.  It's too much guessing without seeing full example code. `plt.ylim` only works for the "current" subplot.

Comment: I added problematic part of the code. The numbers that variables contain is correct.

Comment: The problem seems to be `np.arange(y_lim_min,y_lim_max,5)`.  `np.arange` doesn't include the end value.  You can use `np.arange(y_lim_min, y_lim_max+1, 5)` instead.  Try `print(np.arange(y_lim_min,y_lim_max,5))` to see which values it includes.  Do you really think this type of question is answerable without showing the code?

Comment: Prefect!! Problem solved.  Many thanks  JohanC !!!